# How to port JS code with dollar sign to svelte

Tags: javascript, animation, svelte, sveltekit

Im trying to get this animated polygon background from codepen working within a svelte component.

https://codepen.io/NyX/pen/bEbKZz

```
$(function () {
  const $polygons = $('.bg > polygon');

  const ANIM = {
    duration: 0.6,
    stagger: 0.005,

    from: {
      opacity: 0,
      scale: 0,
      transformOrigin: 'center center',
      force3D: true },


    to: {
      opacity: 1,
      scale: 1,
      ease: Elastic.easeInOut,
      force3D: true } };



  const timeline = new TimelineMax({
    delay: 0,
    repeat: 0
    //repeatDelay: 0.5,
    //yoyo: true
  });


  timeline.staggerFromTo($polygons, ANIM.duration, ANIM.from, ANIM.to, ANIM.stagger, 0);
  //TweenMax.staggerFromTo(polygons, ANIM.duration, ANIM.from, ANIM.to, ANIM.stagger);

  $('body').addClass('loaded');
});
```

I've tried a number of things but I cant seem to get it working, I tried making a svelte repl to show my progress but that isnt working either.

I think the source of the issue is not knowing how to handle the $ within the script tags of the svelte component.

Answer (score 1):

The `$` here, is from `jquery` (a library which used to be very popular a long time ago).

You don't need `$(function () {` and `$('body').addClass('loaded');` because svelte will handle that for you (that basically waits for your page to be loaded before executing the function and adds a loaded class on the body).

You can get a reference of your polygon elements using `bind:this` in svelte (instead of using `$('.bg > polygon')`), then you can trigger the animation on the `onMount` function for example. I don't know much about this `TweenMax` thingy, I think you should use animation helpers in svelte to re-create the animation.

Comment: There is multiple occurrences of `$` in @Iena's code, this does not answer the question

Comment: @Akxe I said use `bind:this` to get your dom elements instead of using `jquery` dom selector, so I think it does answer the jquery problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your insights helped me rebuild it in a way that makes more sense for svelte.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should *avoid* querying the DOM which is what jQuery (the `$` utility) is for. To get a reference to elements in Svelte you can either use `bind:this` or apply an action via [`use:`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action).

If you really have to query the DOM, you also do not necessarily need jQuery, as browsers now support querying anyway.

But if you need jQuery, e.g. to use some of its many plugins, you can usually import it directly from its NPM package and thus avoid using its globally defined shortcut (`$`).

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery'; // jQuery == $
```

In this specific example, jQuery is completely unnecessary, though, and could be replaced with `querySelectorAll`.

For the animation, you can also import `gsap` directly. The code appears to use a very old version. In newer versions you would do it slightly differently.

When querying the DOM, I would recommend to at the very least use `bind:this` or an action on the root element, so selections become relative and do not accidentally affect anything outside the component. (When using `bind:this` you can only access the bound value after `onMount`.)

Full example using an action:

```html
<script>
    import jQuery from 'jquery';
    import gsap from 'gsap'
    
    function animate(node) {
        const polygons = jQuery(node).find('polygon');
        const ANIM = {
            duration: 0.6,
            stagger: 0.005,
            from: {
                opacity: 0,
                scale: 0,
                transformOrigin: 'center center',
                force3D: true
            },
            to: {
                opacity: 1,
                scale: 1,
                ease: 'elastic',
                force3D: true
            }
        };

        const timeline = gsap.timeline({
            delay: 0,
            repeat: 0,
        });

        timeline.staggerFromTo(polygons, ANIM.duration, ANIM.from, ANIM.to, ANIM.stagger, 0);
    }
</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     use:animate
     width="100%" height="100%">
  ...
</svg>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e925b90e0b0742299df15173cbb77cc8?version=3.50.1)

Added a `viewBox` to scale down the SVG contents. And as noted, jQuery could just be replaced:

```js
const polygons = node.querySelectorAll('polygon');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I decided to do it in a way that doesnt use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the responses. With **@httpete**'s insights, I rebuilt the logic in a way that makes more sense for svelte.

https://svelte.dev/repl/28905c0b02fa43278e77d9adc9b76d44?version=3.50.1

First, I rebuilt the definition of the polygons into a JSON file and then used each loop to construct the SVG. Then I used a svelte transition to animate it. The animation isn't perfect but works, feel free to comment on how to make it look better. Once again thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Better also include the important code also in the answer instead of just linking to the Repl

Comment: *"The animation isnt perfect but works, feel free to comment on how to make it look better."* use H.B.'s answer without jQuery :)